# ASP.net core using an anchor tag to work like a form

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net core razor engine.  Is there a way to get an anchor tag to access my Create method like a form tag does.  I tested my code using a form tag and it works, is there a way to have the anchor tag do the same?

Here is my code

```
<div id = "menu">
    @model ecommerce.Models.Users
    <a asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Create" method="post" role="form">Test</a>  // This is the anchor tag that I want to have the same behavior as the form tag below

    <form asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Create" method="post" role="form">

    <button type="submit">Add to Quotes</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: why you want anchor tag to work like form tag ? Why not use form tag helper itself ? What exactly is your expected behavior ?

Comment: @Shyju, I want to go to my create method and than direct to another page

Comment: the link (anchor tag) does that. What are you missing ? Why you want that to behave like a form ?

Comment: @Aaron In your create method you can redirect what ever page you want.  That is a server side decision and has nothing to do with an anchor tag.

Comment: @nurdyguy, what I am having trouble is using my anchor tag to access my create method.  Using the form I have no problem.  How would I do that using my anchor tag?

Comment: @Aaron That is because your anchor tag will attempt to do a `GET` request but the create method requires a `POST` request.  Just use the form and then redirect afterwards, or create a second `GET` method and point the anchor to that one.

Comment: @nurdyguy, thanks post your answer so I can give you credit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that an anchor tag will create a `GET` request and a form post will be a `POST` request.  That's why your anchor will not hit the same create method as your form post.

If you just want to redirect the user after the form post then just do a normal form post and redirect them at the end of the create method.  This is a very common thing.

If you really want the anchor to point to a create method then create a second version of the method which is a `GET` and point the anchor tag there.

Answer (score 3):

@nurdyguy's answer explains well why it does not work.

Here is how you can get anchor element to do post request:

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOff" method="post">
  <a onclick="this.parentElement.submit()">Log off</a>
  or using a jQuery:
  <a onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()">Log off</a>
</form>
```