# How to delete rows from table when clicking button

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm wondering how I can delete all rows from my Alerts table in the database. I'm using ASP.NET Core in combination with Entity Framework. When I click the delete button right now I'll get an Error 404 (not found)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Controller**

```
private readonly FrontlineDbContext _dbContext;

public class AlertsController : Controller{

public AlertsController( FrontlineDbContext dbContext)
{
    
    _dbContext = dbContext;
} 

[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public void Delete()
{
    var alertsList = _dbContext.Alerts.ToList();
    _dbContext.Alerts.RemoveRange(alertsList);

    _dbContext.SaveChanges();

    //displays a success message after updating, as stated in the Shared>_Layout
    TempData["message"] = $"Alerts have been deleted";
}
}
```

**AlertsView**

```
<h1>Alerts Overview</h1>

<a asp-action="Delete"> Delete Alerts</a>
```

Comment: I think you need to add the `asp-controller` attribute.(`asp-controller="Alerts"`) If the anchor renders anything it would likely be pointing to "/Delete" rather than "/Alerts/Delete" which would result in the 405.

Comment: See this Question: [ASP.net core using an anchor tag to work like a form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41619122)

Comment: adding `asp-controller="alerts"` didn't make a difference. It's pointing to /Alerts/Delete but it's still giving an 405 error

Comment: I believe you need to decorate you method with [HttpDelete].  405 is not Not Found, it is Method Not Allowed, which means the function is not properly configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view code is generating an GET request which is not reaching the `Delete` action method, because it is marked with `[HttpPost]` attribute.

To generate a POST request, and reach your `Delete` method, modify your view code as -

```
<form asp-action="Delete">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-link"/>
</form>
```

Also, replace `[HttpPost]` with `[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]` on the action method, just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

The 405 error  - Method Not Allowed error. I think that is because

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

Remove this attribute for testing and see if it works.

Since ancor tag usually generates GET request it is better to remove [httpPost] attribute too.

Also change your code to this, you didn't  put Controller as your base class

```
....

[Route("[Controller]/[Action]")]
public AlertsController( FrontlineDbContext dbContext):Controller
{
    
    _dbContext = dbContext;
} 


[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public IActionResult Delete()
{
    var alertsList = _dbContext.Alerts.ToList();
      if (alertsList == null) return Ok();
    _dbContext.Alerts.RemoveRange(alertsList);
   var result=_dbContext.SaveChanges();
   if(result >0)
   {
    //displays a success message after updating, as stated in the Shared>_Layout
    TempData["message"] = $"Alerts have been deleted";
     return Ok();
     }
 return BadRequest("Items not deleted");
}
```

and change your view code:

```
<a asp-controller="Alerts" asp-action="Delete"> Delete</a>
```

Comment: This still returns an 405 error . I forgot to put my `public class AlertsController : Controller` . I have edited my question